# The Nagell-Ljunngren Equation

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have been trying to find the papers of Nagell and Ljunngren, which deal with the equation $$\frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1} = y^2$$  and solve it completely. Many papers cite these papers, but I haven't found them anywhere. If anyone can provide some information, I would be very grateful.

Here are some links of the papers which cite it: 
http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/PredaYann1.ps

http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102620327

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm68/cm6822.pdf

Comment: If "many papers cite them", wouldn't it be a good idea to give explicitly the name and other directions of those papers?

Comment: Bogdan should list some of the papers he's read, but a simple Google search turns up quite a few, such as this Bennett-Levin paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4037v1 which by the way considers $y$ to higher powers.

Comment: Can you read French and Dutch? That seems to me like it might be the bigger hurdle.

Comment: No, I can't ;D.But since they are so widely cited, I would guess they are translated.

Comment: You'd be surprised. A lot of Euler's correspondence has yet to be translated, for example.

Comment: Nevertheless, I am interested in the way in which this is solved.I was thinking cyclotomic polynomials, but I really don't know.

Comment: Hi: I posted an answer to this question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/206830/26538) on MO.